# Trouble Getting Subscriber Count on List through API

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am looking to use the ExactTarget API to get the subscriber counts of some of our lists.

I have been trying to work from the .NET sample provided here:
https://code.exacttarget.com/question/how-can-you-check-subscriber-count-list-using-soap-api-without-exporting-subscribers

The code I have right now is at the bottom of this post.

What happens when I run it is: it takes an awfully long time (over 5-10 min) to get past the line:

```
"status = framework.Retrieve(rr, out requestID, out Results);"
```

And when it does finally finish that Retrieve, it claims there are 0 subscribers on the listId provided (by returning a Results object of length 0), when I have verified that there are actually many. So, the function takes forever and returns a totalResults value of 0.

If anyone knows what might be causing this, I'd appreciate the help/advice. Thanks!!

---

```
private int RetrieveSubscriberCount(string ListUsername, string ListPassword, string listId)
    {
         try
            {
            //Retrieve Subscribers for list 
            SoapClient framework = new SoapClient();
            framework.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = ListUsername;
            framework.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = ListPassword;

            //Local variables
            APIObject[] Results;
            String requestID;
            String status;
            ListSubscriber listSub = new ListSubscriber();
            int totalResults = 0;

            // Instantiate the retrieve request
            RetrieveRequest rr = new RetrieveRequest();
            rr.ObjectType = "ListSubscriber";

            // Setting up a simple listid filter
            SimpleFilterPart sf = new SimpleFilterPart();
            sf.SimpleOperator = SimpleOperators.equals;
            sf.Property = "ListID";
            sf.Value = new String[] { listId };

            //Add Filter and properties
            rr.Filter = sf;
            rr.Properties = new string[] { "SubscriberKey", "Status" };

            do
            {
                status = framework.Retrieve(rr, out requestID, out Results);
                totalResults += Results.Length;
            }
            while (status.Equals("MoreDataAvailable"));//This means there are more than 2500 records

            Console.WriteLine("Total Subscribers in List " + listId + ": " + totalResults);
            return totalResults;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Error in RetrieveSubscriberCount: " + ex.Message, "Error - RetrieveSubscriberCount", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            return 0;

        }
    }
```